# Runtime computed Enums TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

Quick question, is this possible in TypeScript? I'm aware that string literals are allowed, why aren't normal strings allowed?

```
import * as path from 'path';

enum Path {
    Root = path.parse(__dirname).root as Path
}
```

Output:

```
application/libs/enums.ts:23:12 - error TS2352: Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Path' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

23     Root = path.parse(__dirname).root as Path
```

Comment: `path.parse(__dirname).root as Path` you are getting some sort of string and type asserting that it's `Path` but at the time of the assertion, it's not. I bet this can confuse the compiler even normally but in TS the enums are supposed to be pre-computed so the compiler can verify their usage during compilation. And you can't really do, if the generation happens post-compilations. Not sure if it's possible to enable some rule to allow it but it also seems you don't want an enum but probably a map of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of TypeScript is to have 'transpilation' from TS to JS. Enums are usually a strong language feature at the same level as data types and used to enforce type safety.

Dynamically generating enums is a level above the transpiler, some kind of meta language, it could be achieved using external tools in your toolchain generating typescript before the transpiler runs, but this would probably not integrate well with your editor/IDE. The whole thing would probably be contrary to the goal of TypeScript unless you want to fully generate everything, transpile and never modify it later.

Comment: Ah I see, so Enums are a *type* of constant then, or in other words: Not all constants have to be Enums in TypeScript?

Comment: @KarlMorrison It seems in some cases enums can be computed: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members